# How to check the Date format of a column in Pyspark

Tags: regex, dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark

I am really new to pyspark, I am facing an issue with regex. So, I have a date column I want to check if the rows of a column are in date format`(dd/mm/yyyy)`. I know how to do it in normal python but not aware of pyspark, Can anybody help with this?

my code:

```
df = 
    Date     name
0 12/12/2020  a
1 24/01/2019  b
2 08/09/2018  c
3 12/24/2020  d


print(re.search('\d.*\/.*\d.*\/.*\d', str(df['Date'])))
```

which gives:

```
<re.Match object; span=(2, 54), match="12/12/2020', '24/01/2019', '08/09/2018', '12/24/2020>
```

How to do the same in `pyspark`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to convert it to a date. If you got null, the format might be wrong:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('converted', F.to_date('Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))
```

PS your way of checking is not very robust - e.g. 01/24/2019 will pass your test, but is not a valid date in dd/MM/yyyy format.

If you want to check against a regex pattern, you can use `rlike`:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('converted', F.col('Date').rlike('\d.*\/.*\d.*\/.*\d'))
```

If you want to extract the pattern,

```
df2 = df.withColumn('converted', F.regexp_extract('Date', '(\d.*\/.*\d.*\/.*\d)', 1))
```